# Perform multiple searches at once in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a list of search queries varying in length. Currently I am doing doing one search after another. This obviously takes a while. So I was hoping, that I could use multiple windows/browser at the same time.

The code which has to be performed for each search looks something like this:

```
for query in queries:
    browser.get(url)
    search_bar = browser.find_element('xpath', XPATH).send_keys(query)

    time.sleep(wait_time)

    try:
        ...
        return_data.append(...)
```

One of my ideas was to create a list of browser like this:

```
browsers = [webdriver.Chrome(r'file_path') for i in range(num_of_browsers)]
```

But I didnt know how to assign questions to the browser while not blocking the other browsers. Maybe use threading?

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I got something to work:

### Custom Browser class

```
class Browser(Chrome):
    def __init__(self, path: str, identifier: int):
        super().__init__(path)
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.ready = True
        self.thread: threading.Thread = threading.Thread()
```

### Main BulkSearch class

```
class BulkSearch:
    threads = []
    return_data = []  # Not ordered
    url = URL

    def __init__(self, queries, num_of_browsers=4):
        self.queries = (i for i in queries)
        self.num_of_queries = len(queries)
        self.browsers = [Browser(PATH, i) for i in range(num_of_browsers)]

    def start_search(self):
        for _ in range(self.num_of_queries):
            current_query = next(self.queries)
            ready_browsers = [b for b in self.browsers if b.ready]

            while not ready_browsers:
                time.sleep(1)
                ready_browsers = [b for b in self.browsers if b.ready]

            current_browser = ready_browsers[0]

            self.browsers[current_browser.identifier].ready = False
            self.browsers[current_browser.identifier].thread = threading.Thread(target=self.search, args=[current_browser, current_query])
            self.browsers[current_browser.identifier].thread.start()

        while not all([b.ready for b in self.browsers]):
            time.sleep(0.5)

        quit_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.quit_browsers)
        quit_thread.start()

        return self.return_data

    def search(self, browser, query):
        browser.get(self.url)
        search_bar = browser.find_element('xpath', XPATH)
        search_bar.clear()
        search_bar.send_keys(query)


        try:
            self.return_data.append(DATA)

        except (EXCEPTIONS):
            self.return_data.append(NO RESULT)

        finally:
            self.browsers[browser.identifier].ready = True

    def quit_browsers(self):
        for browser in self.browsers:
            browser.quit()
```

This works by extending the Chrome-Driver class in such a way, that it has a thread and a status assigned. While the browser is working the status is set to be not ready, so that I can the browser, which has finished its work.

This way, it also works when there are less queries than browsers.

Comment: It is more fast about speed and efficient about resources than run multiple python script? For example run multiple cmd